# Difficult to find the active parent class of a page, that should displayed as a submenu of two main menu

Tags: css, wordpress, menuitem

Need to display a wordpress page(url: /prayers/) under two submenu(a-> prayers, b-> prayers), activate the current class, but it's difficult to find the active class.

Tried using CSS and jQuery...

**Css**

```
.navigation-top .current-menu-item > a, 
.navigation-top .current_page_item > a {
    color: red;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<li id="menu-item-651354" class="withic mnu-learn menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-top-level menu-item-top-level-3 active-parent-item dropdown_ul_available current-menu-item" style="">
    <a href="#" itemprop="url" style="cursor: default;">
        <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
        <span class="avia-menu-text">Learn</span>
        <span class="avia-menu-fx">
            <span class="avia-arrow-wrap">
                <span class="avia-arrow"></span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown_available"></span>
    </a>


<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
    <li id="menu-item-650298" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children active-parent-item">
        <a href="/preschool/" itemprop="url">
            <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
            <span class="avia-menu-text">PRESCHOOL</span>
        </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
        <li id="menu-item-651346" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page page_item page-item-509 current_page_item current-menu-item">
            <a href="/#top" itemprop="url">
                <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
                <span class="avia-menu-text">Punims</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
</li>
</ul>
</li>


<li id="menu-item-650312" class="withic mnu-engage menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-ancestor menu-item-has-children menu-item-top-level menu-item-top-level-4 dropdown_ul_available current-menu-item" style="">
    <a href="#" itemprop="url" style="cursor: default;">
        <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
        <span class="avia-menu-text">Engage</span>
        <span class="avia-menu-fx">
            <span class="avia-arrow-wrap">
                <span class="avia-arrow"></span>
            </span>
        </span>
        <span class="dropdown_available"></span>
    </a>


<ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block; opacity: 1; visibility: visible;">
    <li id="menu-item-650351" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children">
        <a href="/socialize/" itemprop="url">
            <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
            <span class="avia-menu-text">SOCIALIZE</span>
        </a>
    <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: block; opacity: 0; visibility: hidden;">
        <li id="menu-item-650793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-ancestor current-menu-parent current_page_parent current_page_ancestor menu-item-has-children">
            <a href="/young-families/" itemprop="url">
                <span class="avia-bullet"></span>
                <span class="avia-menu-text">Punims</span>
            </a>
</li>
    </ul>
</li>


</ul>
</li>
```

It activates both menus and also need  not to set parent page in admin, because need to display this page under two menus.

Is any alternative method available without using plugins.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You also need to post the rendered HTML and in this case a link to your page if it's hosted somewhere as it's WordPress

Comment: Updated my html code

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the standard menu in Appearance -> Menus to generate the menus?

If so Wordpress will automatically add the active class. All you have to do is style it.

If you post your link or the code for the LI we can direct you.

Comment: yes using standard Menu, same page under two menus, its automatically activate active class for both menus, but i needed to activate only one menu at a time.. is its possible..

Comment: You can override that. Get the page id class in the header and then target it with style.

Comment: Do you need the 2nd menu to have active states at any time while on these pages?

Comment: actually the same page is displayed under two menu so the page id is same, I need to activate the main menu when the corresponding submenu is clicked.

Comment: Updated HTML in my question

Comment: Ah, you will then need js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197153/discussion-between-renjitha-and-shado).